# How to create a custom JSON payload structure in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API that requires custom structure for all JSON responses.

```
{
    code: 200,
    payload: [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Where `payload` contains all the items returned by the query.

I've created a custom `Renderer` that extends `JSONRenderer` but in order to access the response code I need to access the `render_context`.

```
class VendorRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, render_context=None):
        response = render_context['response']
        data = {
            'code': response.status_code,
            'payload': data
        }
        return super(VendorRenderer, self).render(data, accepted_media_type, render_context)
```

Is this the right place to be doing this kind of wrapping or should it be taking place somewhere else like the ViewSet or by extending the Response object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct place to wrap the response because responses are rendered after error checking is performed in the middleware.

Doing it in the view may cause unexpected results as, for example a serialization error won't be caught correctly by your `code` parameter and wrapping it in a custom serializer won't have access to the response object. Also, you may want authentication or throttling errors to be wrapped in your response.

Be aware that any pagination that happens is also going to be wrapped in your `payload` parameter:

```
{
    "code":200,
    "payload": {
        "count": 20,
        "next": 2,
        "previous": 0,
        "results": [
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

One solution to this is to implement pagination using HTTP headers.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response 

class StandardResultsSetHeaderPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        headers = {
            'X-Count':    self.page.paginator.count,
            'X-Next':     self.get_next_link(),
            'X-Previous': self.get_previous_link()
        }
        return Response(data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: The pagination is a bit frustrating, but I suppose I can figure out how to extract that into the structure as we were considering a `meta` field for that sort of thing anyways.

Comment: I agree with you. I faced a similar problem and relocated the pagination to the header of the request. Here's my implementation: https://dpaste.de/6swb

Comment: Thanks, I've added your snippet to the answer.